# Loop through two pandas dataframes

Tags: loops, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` as shown below:

```
df1:

Month    Count
6        314
6        418
6        123
7        432

df2:

Month  ExpectedValue
6       324
7       512
8       333
```

I have to loop through `df1` and `df2`. If `df1['Month'] == 6`, then I have to loop through `df2` to get the expected value for month 6. Then, I will have the field in `df1` as `df1['ExpectedValue']`.

Output like this below:

```
df1:

Month   Count    ExpectedValue
6        314        324 
6        418        324
6        123        324
7        432        512
```

Is looping through 2 dataframes an efficient idea? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it should be 512

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't loop over DataFrames unless it's absolutely necessary. You'll usually get better performance using a built-in Pandas function that's already been optimized, or by using a vectorized approach.  This will usually result in cleaner code too.

In this case you can use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Month')
```

The resulting output:

```
   Month  Count  ExpectedValue
0      6    314            324
1      6    418            324
2      6    123            324
3      7    432            512
```